# What's the problem in the following paragraph?

Tags: lateral-thinking

Brian wrote:

> Hi, my name is Brian. I love to play video games, and write stories. Nobody is better than me at it! The only problem is I'm running out of story ideas. Can you help me? Pitch some ideas! Thanks

He posted it on a billboard. A week later he got a call saying something was wrong with his note. Brian spent hours trying to find something wrong with it. He never found it. What was wrong with the paper?

Comment: I was considering editing the punctuation, but apparently the incorrect punctuation is part of the answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that if "Nobody is better than me at it!" than nobody can help Brian, if he is out of ideas then anyone else will be out of ideas for sure.

---

Concluding, we must say that the reader must not pay attention to the one. Either Brian is telling truth and reader has no chance to help him, or Brian is a liar and then the statement that he needs help may be is a lie too.

Comment: Correct. It was also missing a period!

Comment: @warspyking,   
"It was also missing a period!"  
lol)

Comment: I disagree with this answer.  Just because he is the best doesn't mean that other people can't help.  Brian may know the most story ideas (making him the best) but that doesn't mean he knows them all.  All one needs to do to help is know a single story idea that Brian does not...

Comment: @Trenin, I agree, but this is subjective logic. Here I try to use objective criteria only, otherwise we can not conclude nothing objective. Objectively if Brian doesn't know everything that... lets say Tom do knows and vice versa, then it is hard to say who is the best. What is better potato with salat or with meat? Different people would answer differently. The only case we can objectively say the Brian is better than Tom if Brian does everything that Tom does plus something extra.